# delete record if there is a new Record mongo

Tags: sql, mongodb

I want to convert the below sql query to mongo
can any one help

````
delete from table t 
join (
( select tenantid , max(date) date from 
table where date < currentdate-30 group by tenantid)  q 
on t.tenantid = q.tenantid and t.date < q.date```
````

Comment: add sample data

Comment: {
tenantid: ten1,
date: 27-06-2021
}
{
tenantid: ten1,
date: 30-07-2021
}
{
tenantid: ten1,
date: 30-08-2021
}
in the above scenario, it should delete the 1st record  
subquery get tenant id and latest record 30 days before from today 
so its {
tenantid: ten1,
date: 30-07-2021
}
then we remove the record older than this record